# Axes in tikz, figure shows but there is a compiling error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code to draw four axes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below];
  \draw[shift={(0,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below];
  \draw (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[left];
  \draw[shift={(0,0)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left]; 
  \node[below] at (0,-3.20) {\footnotesize label1};
  \node[above] at (0,3.20) {\footnotesize label2};
  \node[right] at (3.20, 0) {\footnotesize label3};
  \node[left] at (-3.20, 0) {\footnotesize label4};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When compiling, I got the following error:

```
"! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text"
```

Is there another error free way of labeling?

Comment: By uncommenting your code, you can find the exact line that is causing trouble, and by modifying and comparing, you can find what in that line is wrong. Here is what you will finde: `A node must have a (possibly empty) label text`

Answer (score 3):

You need to give a label text to a `node`, an empty one `{}` would be enough:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {}; % empty label text
\draw[shift={(0,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {}; % empty label text
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[left] {}; % empty label text
\draw[shift={(0,0)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {}; % empty label text
\node[below] at (0,-3.20) {\footnotesize label1};
\node[above] at (0,3.20) {\footnotesize label2};
\node[right] at (3.20, 0) {\footnotesize label3};
\node[left] at (-3.20, 0) {\footnotesize label4};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you just want a named position, you can simply use `coordinate`. In your case, nodes in the `\draw` commands seems unnecessary (they don't have label texts and come with no name to be referred to later), an easier way is to draw the nodes inside paths:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-3) node[below] {label1} -- (0,3) node[above] {label2};
\draw (-3,0) node[left] {label4} -- (3,0) node[right] {label3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We are adding `{}` at the end of nodes. I enclose the code, we run any LaTeX engine.

```
% *latex mal-nodes.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below] {}; % We added {} here,
   \draw[shift={(0,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {}; % change is here,
   \draw (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[left] {}; % plus here,
   \draw[shift={(0,0)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {}; % and also on this line.
   \node[below] at (0,-3.20) {\footnotesize label1};
   \node[above] at (0,3.20) {\footnotesize label2};
   \node[right] at (3.20, 0) {\footnotesize label3};
   \node[left] at (-3.20, 0) {\footnotesize label4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: an example: all nodes with empty text]